# Get data and uploaded files from android (mobile) version of website

Tags: 7

I built a website and it works well in browser. We need to create android version of this website, and in this version users must be able to log in to the site and upload images in their profile.

I really have no idea how Drupal does this and how can I let that android software to connect to my website, upload images and data. I would be appreciated for any help.

thanks.

Comment: you are looking to build mobile app or website?

Comment: Some one else is going to build this application. He needs to connect to my website and be able to login, send data and upload image to a content type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu need to provide services using RESTful API to mobile app developer. Required modules are [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services), [services definition](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_definition) and rest server through it you can connect to mobile application because it returns json or xml. Thorugh our site endpoint. Further you can go to its tutorial [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1973214).